# Specifying the font in `\newcommand` (for math)

Tags: math-mode, macros, equations, amsmath

I want to specify a single letter (the letter 'A') with a different font than in the rest of my paper. Can I do that easily using `\newcommand`? The letter will be used in equations.

Edit: the letter 'A' that I want to specify in a different font has a special meaning. Thus, I want to be able to write a normal 'A' (which has no other meaning than being another regular letter) as well as an 'A' with a specific meaning (a vector potential, if you are curious).

Comment: Said in other words: you want that all A's in math mode to be printed, say, upright? Please, be a bit more specific.

Comment: @egreg, see my edit.

Comment: Yes, you can do this.  (This is basic knowledge.)  For example, `\newcommand(\myA}{\mathcal{A}}` and be sure to use `\myA` in an environment that is specified as math.

Comment: It's not basic knowledge for someone new to Latex. How do I define the font used by \mathcal (I want to define this font only for this one letter)? mathcal is not a font in itself.

Comment: @Physics101 the best way to specify a certain font is dependent on the font itself, and the used TeX engine. Can you please provide a small minimal example and tell us which engine you use and which font you want to use for the A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, look at the math alphabets you already have available, such as `\mathcal{A}`, and see if any of them meet your needs. Then, check font packages such as `unicode-math`, `mathalpha`, `isomath` and `amssymb` to see if they have one that suits you, such as `\mathfrak{A}`.

If not, you can use the `\text` command from `amsmath`/`amstext` to insert any text-mode symbol in math mode.  For example, this inserts a Gothic A from the `yfonts` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\mathgoth[1]{\mathord{\text{\usefont{U}{ygoth}{m}{n} #1}}}
\newcommand\mswabA{\mathgoth{A}}

\newcommand\diff[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{d} #1}}

\begin{document}
\[ \mswabA = {-}\oint_\Sigma \frac{\partial B}{\partial t} \cdot \diff{A}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: ygoth font sample]

You could instead use package commands, such as,

```
\usepackage{oldgerm} % For \gothfamily

\newcommand\mathgoth[1]{\mathord{\textnormal{\gothfamily #1}}}
```

If you want the symbol to be aware of math versions, and respect `\boldmath` or `\boldsymbol`, you will have to `\DeclareMathAlphabet` and `\SetMathAlphabet`.  Be aware that legacy TeX is limited to sixteen 8-bit math alphabets.

Comment: Thank you. I used ´\DeclareMathAlphabet´ and got what I was looking for.